# Ubuntu-SDK cannot start qtcreator

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-sdk, qt5

I cannot start `qtcreator` with `ubuntu-sdk` installed. I'm getting error:

```
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Follow Symbol Under Cursor" under id 142 
loaded the dummy plugin 
loaded the Linux plugin 
Registered the AalSensorPlugin types 

Segmentation fault  (core dumped)
```

When I removed `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu` I was able to start `qtcreator`. There has to be bug in `ubuntu-sdk` plugins.

I'm running ubuntu 13.10 64 bit. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

First of all , this is possible to do.

core always dumped because of your wrong configuration (i recommend to use i386 ).
simply delete these configuration folders :

`rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntu-sdk/`

`rm -rf ~/.config/Qtproject/`

then restart ubuntu-sdk

Finally relax and you're welcome.

Comment: "When I removed qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu I was able to start qtcreator" – Why should your answer help?